# How to publish a .NET (C#) program to AWS BeanStalk in a Linux environment?

Tags: c#, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I use the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio, I get the option of "Container type", but that list only contains Windows:

[image]

Can this be worked around somehow, so I get the full backing of Beanstalk, but I want it running in a Linux environment (.NET core)?

I have googled and looked around here on SO, but frankly, most of the answers are unclear or not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Ted, have you tried [AWS EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)? You can do everything with it, as you do in the AWS Console.

Comment: Thx... I havent tried it, and reading up on it, it seems a bit crazy to use that. Those commands are many and very long. To figure those out is... I mean, look at this beauty :-) `~$ aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment --cname-prefix my-cname --application-name my-app --version-label v1 --environment-name my-env --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)"`

Comment: It's just a series of options...I would imagine the documentation explains what each one is used for. Most of the text in your example is just an arbitrary description for the environment. If you want to shorten the command then just set `--solution-stack-name="x"` instead.... :-)

Comment: Well, I would suggest that you create your environment via AWS Console and use only AWS EB CLI to **deploy** your application. Can I put the suggestion as the answer for your question?

Comment: So, AWS Toolkit doesnt have presets, meaning you need to manually create an environment, and then, afterwards, tell BeanStalk to use that specific environment? You get an unique name for the image, I assume, an AMI? I noted that the AWS Toolkit allowed you to specify an AMI (id nbr I assume).

Comment: Yes, I didn't have searched deeper on AWS CLI to look for automatic setup of environments, but I think it's possible. And yes, you get an AMI and then you can specify which one is it.

Comment: On my configurations I always use the simplest one: have everything configured and then go to the project folder and use _eb deploy_

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is not a Linux .NET Core offering for the Elastic Beanstalk service. The the easiest way to deploy an ASP.NET Core application to Linux from Visual Studio is as a Docker application to AWS Fargate.

In Visual Studio if you right click on the project and select Add -> Docker Support to have Visual Studio generate a Dockerfile then the Publish Container to AWS option will show up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In linux environments you can use AWS CLI applications to every AWS Service. In your case you can use [AWS EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html).

**Tip**: Create your default environment on AWS Console and then use only the *eb deploy* command to deploy your application. It's less painfull, otherwise you can create everything from terminal.